# how to send / receive TObjectList by DataSnap solving the memory leak?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe6, datasnap, tobjectlist

Prototype of a client application and DataSnap server. I want to transmit a **TObjectList** from the server to the client.

This is working , but all the objects that I convey remain in memory on the server and the client.

What am I doing wrong ?

Lifecycle = Session

The TPessoa object implements a TObjectList of another class (TConta):

```
   TConta = class(TObject)
  private
    FBanco: string;
    FConta: Integer;
    FAgencia: Integer;
    procedure SetAgencia(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetBanco(const Value: string);
    procedure SetConta(const Value: Integer);
   published
     property Banco : string read FBanco write SetBanco;
     property Agencia : Integer read FAgencia write SetAgencia;
     property Conta : Integer read FConta write SetConta;
   end;

   TContasCollection = TObjectList<TConta>;

   TPessoa = class(TObject)
  private
    FContas: TContasCollection;
    FId: Integer;
    FNome: string;
    procedure SetContas(const Value: TContasCollection);
    procedure SetId(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetNome(const Value: string);
   published
     property Id : Integer read FId write SetId;
     property Nome : string read FNome write SetNome;
     property Contas : TContasCollection read FContas write SetContas;
   end;
```

Method public in ServerMetodsUnit :

```
function getPessoa(id : Integer) : Tpessoa;

function TServerMethods1.getPessoa(id: Integer): Tpessoa;
begin
  result := Tpessoa.create;
  result.id := id;
  result.nome := 'NoName';
  result.contas := getContas;
end;

function TServerMethods1.getContas: TContasCollection;
var conta : TConta;
begin
  conta := TConta.Create;
  conta.Banco := 'CEF';
  conta.Agencia := 1;
  conta.Conta := 123;

  Result := TContasCollection.Create();
  Result.Add(conta);
end;
```

Client:

```
procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var pessoa : Tpessoa;
begin
  pessoa := ClientModule1.ServerMethods1Client.getPessoa(1);
  mmo1.Lines.Add(pessoa.Nome);
  mmo1.Lines.Add(pessoa.Contas[0].Banco);
end;
```

correct result, however the memory leak message is displayed in the Server and the Client (System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;):

> Unexpected Memory Leak An unexpected memory leak has occurred. The
>   unexpected small block leaks are:
>
> 1 - 12 bytes: TMoveArrayManager x 1, Unknown x 1 13
>   - 20 bytes: TConta x 1, UnicodeString x 1 37 - 44 bytes: TObjectList x 1

how to solve this memory leak not to affect the service ?

Comment: What does the DataSnap documentation say about life time management?

Answer (score 1):

Memory leak occurs because you are not releasing objects you are creating.

For start in client part you are creating `pessoa` object in `btn1Click` as local variable but you are not releasing it.

```
procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var pessoa : Tpessoa;
begin
  pessoa := ClientModule1.ServerMethods1Client.getPessoa(1);
  mmo1.Lines.Add(pessoa.Nome);
  mmo1.Lines.Add(pessoa.Contas[0].Banco);
  pessoa.Free; // you are no longer using pessoa object after that point so release it
end;
```

`TPessoa` class has `FContas` field that we don't see how is created or released, maybe you have just omitted the code, and maybe it is not there at all. Anyway, `FContas` has also be released at some point. If `TPessoa` class is owner of `FContas` field (and it looks like it should be) then you would have to add destructor to `TPessoa` class where you would free `FContas` collection.

`FContas` is `TObjectList` that by default owns added objects and those would be released when `FContas` is released.

There is also possible leak of `FContas` object in `SetContas` method, but without knowing how that code looks it is hard to tell is it leaking or not.

```
TPessoa = class(TObject)
....
public
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

destructor TPessoa.Destroy; 
begin
  FContas.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure SetContas(const Value: TContasCollection);
begin
  FContas.Free; // release old FContas collection if there is one
  FContas := Value; // reference FContas grabs ownership here 
end;
```

Basically, every object you create you have to free after you no longer need it, unless there is some other object instance that will grab ownership of that object and do it for you, like `TObjectList` does.

Above code assumes that `FContas` field is owner of collection it holds, and it is important that you don't grab that reference and hold it beyond lifetime of it's owner object (`TPessoa`) instance.

For example, following code would be wrong:

```
procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  pessoa : Tpessoa;
  contas: TContasCollection;
begin
  pessoa := ClientModule1.ServerMethods1Client.getPessoa(1);
  contas := pessoa.Contas;
  pessoa.Free; // <-- after that point contas points to released object
  mmo1.Lines.Add(contas[0].Banco); // <-- dangling pointer use
end;
```

There are also reference counted object instances that are automatically released after the last reference to them goes out of scope (usually descendants of `TInterfacedObject` class), but managing those is completely different story. You are not using them here and I am mentioning them only for completeness.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know in particular how DataSnap manages lifetime of objects (and which ones)... but in above code there is no evidence that DataSnap manages lifetime of objects in question...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Sorry, I did not add the clases generated by the wizard datasnap Customer ( ClientModule and ClientClasses ) , they do account for connecting to the server and pass the result.
By using the pessoa.Free as suggested , an exception is generated  (Exception EInvalidPointer in module Cliente.exe at 00008165. Invalid pointer operation.) and the list of leaks is huge .

Comment: OK, just found out that DataSnap is managing lifetime of objects returned by default. That is the part that confused me a bit, because if objects are managed then you would have no leak at all, and if they are not then `pessoa.Free` would have to be called. However, it is possible that you are leaking `FContas` collection because you call `getContas` inside `getPessoa` function. If that is the case, then adding destructor to `TPessoa` class would suffice to clear the leak.